# Linking html pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on a web application. I came across a problem: if I want to hide text in for example 03.hoofdstuk 3.html [pages][1] i have a checkbox that can be checked in 01.algemeen.html

I am looking for a way to hide the headers and paragraphs across 2 different pages. I tried hide element by id (with all an unique id) but that didnt work. (maybe because the pages werent linked?)
How do I stop the html from reloading when you go back to the page? (for example: when I check the checkbox in 01.algemeen.html, I take a look in 03.hoofdstuk 3.html if the headers and paragraphs are hidden and go back, the checkbox in 01.algemeen.html is back unchecked.)
How I linked the pages:

```html
        <div class="menu-items">
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="01. algemeen.html">
                    <i class="uil uil-estate"></i>
                    <span class="link-name">Algemeen</span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="02. oppervlaktes.html">
                    <i class="uil uil-ruler"></i>
                    <span class="link-name">Oppervlaktes</span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="03. hoofdstuk 3.html">
                    <i class="uil uil-bookmark"></i>
                    <span class="link-name">Hoofdstuk 3</span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="04. hoofdstuk 4.html">
                    <i class="uil uil-bookmark"></i>
                    <span class="link-name">Hoofdstuk 4</span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="05. hoofdstuk 5.html">
                    <i class="uil uil-bookmark"></i>
                    <span class="link-name">Hoofdstuk 5</span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="06. hoofdstuk 6.html">
                    <i class="uil uil-bookmark"></i>
                    <span class="link-name">Hoofdstuk 6</span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="07. hoofdstuk 7.html">
                    <i class="uil uil-bookmark"></i>
                    <span class="link-name">Hoofdstuk 7</span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="08. luchtverversing.html">
                    <i class="uil uil-wind"></i>
                    <span class="link-name">Luchtverversing</span>
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="09. daglicht.html">
                    <i class="uil uil-sun"></i>
                    <span class="link-name">Daglicht</span>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
```

Note: the checkbox is on another page than where the text needs to be hidden. Btw: I am testing it all by opening the html in chrome (not hosting it yet, so it still needs to work without hosting.)

the checkbox on page 01.algemeen.html:

```html
 <div class="text"> Gebruiksfunctie </div>
              <div class="checkboxfunctie">
              <input type="checkbox" id="Woonfunctie"
                      unchecked>
              <label class="checktext" for="Woonfunctie">Woonfunctie</label>
              </div>
```

one of the header and paragraphs i want to hide:

```html
<h3 class="artikel" id="3.8.0">Artikel 3.8 (aansturingsartikel)</h3>

<p id="3.8.1">1. Een bouwwerk is bestand tegen krachten die tijdens het beoogde gebruik op het bouwwerk
          worden uitgeoefend.</p>
```

Hope you understand the problem. Feel free to ask questions!!

Looking forward hearing from you guys!

Comment: Note that the file names in the HTML have spaces in them, but when discussing them in text, you do not put spaces in the file names. That could cause problems.

Comment: HTML can't do that by itself. You have to send the fact that the checkbox(es) is/are checked to the server so the server can omit or hide the parts you want on the next page; sending can be done with an HTML form or Javascript. — *or* you can save the checkbox states in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (or sessionStorage) and read out of localStorage on the next page; this would require Javascript.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Clicking into that link leads to the text page or to the checkbox? Why are you separating the checkbox and the link list?